# Is there a way I can make this into a function or anything more efficient

Tags: javascript

```
if (one >= 16 && one <= 20){
  if (two >= 10){
    Sum.innerHTML = "$2750";
  } else {
    Sum.innerHTML = "$2500";
  }
} else if (one >= 20 && one <= 25){
  if (two >= 10){
    Sum.innerHTML = "$2500";
  } else {
    Sum.innerHTML = "$2250";
  }
}
```

This is just a little of my code, its just a simple money calculator for something I'm doing with a friend, which doesn't really matter. I can't seem to think if there is any way I can make this more efficient by using a function of such because it just seems so much of the same code and is "dry" this is not all the code from it, there is so much of this... Don't know if anyone can help FYI this is in js and Sum is a paragraph id so just think of it as console log.

Thanks, Ethan

**EDIT**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxgYWL?editors=10100
If you go onto that you can see all the code with all the commenting I could think to add to try and help you understand. Don't worry if it doesn't help and if there is no other way to make it efficient. It doesn't REALLY matter because it's just a private bit of code and shouldn't cause many problems.

Comment: Are these the only ranges? Are these (`$2750`, `$2500`, `$2500`, `$2250`) the only possible values? If the answer is NO, then, please, give us a bigger picture of the scenario.

Comment: Since this is an already working code, this might be more suited on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I would probably do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/jrde71vc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first your this part of code:

```
if(two >= 10)
{
    Sum.innerHTML = "$2750";
}
else
{
    Sum.innerHTML = "$2500";
}
```

we could rewrite to more shorter code:

```
Sum.innerHTML = two >= 10 ? "$2750" : "$2500";
```

And then because your this part of code repeats all the time we could write it in function like follows:

```
function setSum(compareValue, ifValue, elseValue)
{
    Sum.innerHTML = two >= compareValue ? ifValue : elseValue
    // or even: Sum.innerHTML = two >= 10 ? ifValue : elseValue
}
```

And after this we can short your code from **[your example on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxgYWL)** like in following example:

```js
var numOne = document.getElementById("one"),
    numTwo = document.getElementById("two"),
    Sum = document.getElementById("sum");

numOne.addEventListener("input", calc);
numTwo.addEventListener("input", calc);

function setSum(compareValue, ifValue, elseValue)
{
    Sum.innerHTML = two >= compareValue ? ifValue : elseValue
    // or even: Sum.innerHTML = two >= 10 ? ifValue : elseValue
}

function calc()
{
    var one = parseFloat(numOne.value) || 0,
        two = parseFloat(numTwo.value) || 0;

    if(one >= 16 && one <= 20)
        setSum(10, "$2750", "$2500");

    else if(one >= 20 && one <= 25)
        setSum(10, "$2500", "$2250");

    else if(one >= 25 && one <= 35)
        setSum(10, "$2000", "$1750");

    else if(one >= 35 && one <= 45)
        setSum(10, "$1500", "$1250");

    else if(one >= 45 && one <= 50)
        setSum(10, "$1250", "$1000");
}
```

```html
<h4>Calculator</h4>
<p>
    <input id="one"> + <input id="two">
</p>
<p id="sum"></p>
```

I do not really understand what your calculater does, but you wrote:

> *This is just a little of my code, its just a simple money calculator for something I'm doing with a friend, which doesn't really matter.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a data structure to hold the range boundaries, then loop over it.

```
var params = [
    { onelow: 16, onehigh: 20, 
      two: [ { low: -inf, high: 9, value: 2500 },
             { low: 10, high: +inf, value: 2750 }],
    },
    { onelow: 21, onehigh: 25, 
      two: [ { low: -inf, high: 9, value: 2250 },
             { low: 10, high: +inf, value: 2500 }],
    },
    ...
];

let done = false;
for(let i = 0; !done && i < params.length; i++) {
    let param = params[i];
    if (one >= param.onelow && one <= param.onehigh) {
        let done = false;
        for (let j = 0; j < param.two.length; j++) {
            let param2 = param[j];
            if (two >= param2.low && two <= param2.high) {
                Sum.innerHTML = "$" + param2.value;
                done = true; // stop the outer loop, too
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your code as following (UPDATED):

```
var temp = "$2500"
if (one >= 16 && one <= 20){  
  if (two >= 10){
    temp = "$2750";
  }
} else if (one >= 20 && one <= 25){
  if (!(two >= 10)){
    temp = "$2250";
  }
}
Sum.innerHTML = temp;
```

You don't always need to write an `else`, it can be avoided like in the above code. If you have to change the value, then set one value that is going to be same always, and change the value if the condition is satisfied.

I hope my answer was meaningful. Thanks.

Comment: If you’re going to do that, you should create a temporary variable in JS and do only 1 actual DOM write. DOM writes are slow, so doing two DOM writes is not more efficient (though it is easier to read).